# Django limit next inlinefield to first inlinefield

Tags: python, django

I have this model in django

```
from django.db import models

class ProductType(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    slug  = models.SlugField(unique=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name


class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    slug  = models.SlugField(unique=True)
    type = models.ForeignKey(ProductType, related_name='product_type')
    related_products = models.ManyToManyField('self',blank=True,null=True)
    description = models.TextField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

What I would like to do is in the admin have the Products as tabular inline to a quote page that have multiple products. This thing is that the first selected model can be a parent to the others and therefore I would like the choices of the next elements to be sorted by the first.

this is the quote model

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils.translation import ugettext as _
import datetime

from products.models import Product
from customers.models import Customer

class Quote(models.Model):
    quoteid = models.IntegerField(_('Quote ID'), max_length=8, unique=True, default=number)
    slug  = models.SlugField(unique=True,default=number)
    add_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer, related_name='quote_customer',blank = True, null = True)
    product = models.ManyToManyField(Product, related_name='quote_product')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return str(self.quoteid)
```

and the admin part

```
from django.contrib import admin

from quotes.models import Quote

class ProductInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Quote.product.through
    extra = 3


class QuoteAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    prepopulated_fields = {'slug': ('quoteid',)}

    fieldsets = (
        (('Quote'), {'fields': ('slug','quoteid','customer',)}),
    )

    list_display = ('quoteid','customer','add_date',)

    inlines = [ ProductInline]


admin.site.register(Quote,QuoteAdmin)
```

I know this is quite tricky and I have tried many ways but I have not found a solution that works. I have tried with formfield_for_manytomany but I can't fully grasp how to return the first tabularinline object as the input for the queryset.

If someone have a link that explains a method to do this I would be grateful.